Strategy Stealing Proof, Second Player Strategy
edit:
Suppose there is some square (x,y) exists as part of Player 2's strategy. Suppose Player 1 chooses (x,y). Is Player 2 still following that strategy on its turn? It can no longer access that square so it has been prevented from following the strategy.  The contradiction comes from both players having a 'winning strategy', but Player 2's strategy has changed.
original intro:
I learned of Chomp and that by the strategy stealing argument, the first player can win.
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1050681 is a great explanation of the proof, but there seems to be an implicit assumption that is broken.  As part of the proof, we assume Player2 has a winning strategy and is using it, but if Player 1 is using it, this prevents Player 2 from using it, and thus isn't guaranteed to win, so there is no contradiction.
original ending:
Player 1, using a winning strategy, must reach some State it is impossible to lose from.  Player 2 cannot reach these states, therefore is not using a winning strategy, therefore there is no contradiction.


As part of the proof, we assume Player2 has a winning strategy and is using it, but if Player 1 is using it, this prevents Player 2 from using it, and thus isn't guaranteed to win, so there is no contradiction.

A "winning strategy", by definition, works no matter what your opponent does.  It doesn't make sense to say, "if Player 1 is using it, this prevents Player 2 from using it".  If Player 1 can prevent player 2 from using the "winning strategy", then it wasn't a winning strategy for player 2 to begin with.

Suppose there is some square (x,y) exists as part of Player 2's strategy.  Suppose Player 1 chooses (x,y).  Is Player 2 still following that strategy?  It can no longer access that square so it has been prevented from following the strategy.

It doesn't make sense to say "Suppose there is some square (x,y) exists as part of Player 2's strategy". That's not how strategies work. A strategy is a complete set of rules which describes, for every position where it is your turn, what move you make.
